# Identify in custom Web API with absolute certainty who is logged in to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, .net-core, jwt, sharepoint-online

My user logs into SharePoint Online and is authenticated.

I have a custom made Web API application which my client side calls.

**I would like to know with absolute certainty which user is calling my API.**

My idea so far is to find the JWT in the cookie in SharePoint (success) which states who is logged in. By sending this along to my custom API I reasonably know who is calling, but how can I trust it?

**Can I somehow verify the JWT even though it was not issued by me?**

Any other ideas to accomplish the same?
(Note, I do not want to introduce Azure AD authentication in my web app. I want to identify the user in a single API call and not have to redirect back and forth first)

FYI: This is the header of the JWT issued after logging into SharePoint:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "x478xyOplsM1H7NXk7Sx17x1upc",
  "kid": "x478xyOplsM1H7NXk7Sx17x1upc"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the public configuration for O365:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

This sample in .NET Core validates the JWT:

```
string stsDiscoveryEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";

ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());

OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;

TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateAudience = false,
    ValidateIssuer = false,
    ValidateLifetime = false,
    IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys
};

JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokendHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

var token = "JWT TOKEN TO VALIDATE HERE";

SecurityToken jwt;
var result = tokendHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out jwt);

return jwt as JwtSecurityToken;
```

It requires these using statements.

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
```

I used this example to get started, but it didn't work out of the box in .NET Core.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/practice-sharing/2016/03/22/office-365-dev-how-to-validate-the-access-token-issued-by-microsoft-azure-ad/